# Why my AJAX is called every two minutes?

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, mongoose

I have an issue when I'm using my POST ajax function.

I'm running a simple app created by express-generator using node, express, mongodb, mongoose and jade. After I created a module for posting a new object to the database, I have noticed that the POST / DELETE requests are done multiple times. This is happening both on 'on-click' modes and if I change the function to load automatically on load.

Please note: the function is only called once by the user - there are no logs in the browser. It looks like it runs every 2 minutes, and I have absolutely no idea why.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Javascript code:

```
    $('#btn5').on('click', saveFiveDayForecast);


  saveFiveDayForecast = function() {

    var random = {
      city: 'One'
    }

    $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      data: JSON.stringify(random),
      url: '/fiveDay/',
      contentType: 'application/json',
      dataType: 'JSON'
    })  

  }
```

Routing file:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

// DB schema and model setup ----------------------------------------------

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// create 16 day schema
var fiveDaySchema = new Schema({
    city         :   String
}, { collection: 'fiveDayModel' });

// create 16 day model for later manipulation in routing files
var fiveDayModel = mongoose.model('fiveDayModel', fiveDaySchema);

// END DB schema and model setup -------------------------------------------

/* POST */
router.post('/', function(req, res) {
    var time = new Date();

    var fiveDayWeatherToSave = new fiveDayModel( req.body );

    console.log('post in the routing file was fired at: ');
    console.log(time);

    fiveDayWeatherToSave.save(function (err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        else console.log('Saved ', data );
    });

});
```

Logs from node:

The node logs are interesting: when the data is saved first time there is no POST line in it, yet the data is saved anyway.

```
post in the routing file was fired at:
Wed May 13 2015 14:40:06 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)
Saved  { __v: 0, city: 'One', _id: 55535436f0ee99bc1d790220 }
POST /fiveDay/ - - ms - -
post in the routing file was fired at:
Wed May 13 2015 14:42:06 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)
Saved  { __v: 0, city: 'One', _id: 555354aef0ee99bc1d790221 }
POST /fiveDay/ - - ms - -
```

Comment: There is no reason in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browsers will retry a request if it fails due to a timeout.  Since you never return a response, this will always happen.  You should respond with something like `res.end()` or `res.send("success!")`.